# MySQL BETWEEN vs. bigger than and smaller than

Tags: mysql, url-rewriting, system, between

I have a working reservation query. This query checks which items are available for the time of reservation.

[PROJECT]: projectid, datefrom, dateto, ...
[ITEM]: itemid, itemgroupid, ...
[ITEMGROUP]: itemgroupid, itemgroupname, ...
[RESERVELIST]: itemid, projectid, reservelistnr

```
SELECT *
FROM item i inner join itemgroup ig on i.itemgroupid = ig.itemgroupid
WHERE i.itemid NOT IN  (
                        SELECT r.itemid 
                        FROM reservelist r inner join project p on r.projectid = p.projectid
                        WHERE p.datefrom BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'
                        OR p.dateto BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'
                        OR '$datefrom' BETWEEN p.datefrom AND p.dateto
                        OR '$dateto' BETWEEN p.datefrom AND p.dateto
                        )
ORDER BY itemid
```

$datefrom and $dateto are the dates of the time of reservation. 
Now this query works well, but if someone make a reservation between 08:00 - 21:00, the next reservation can only be done at 21:01 and not at 21:00 sharp. So I need to have a smaller than and greater than.

I played alot with the < and >, but somehow it doesn't seem to work.

My best guess is that this should be the good solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM item i inner join itemgroup ig on i.itemgroupid = ig.itemgroupid
WHERE i.itemid NOT IN  (
                        SELECT r.itemid 
                        FROM reservelist r inner join project p on r.projectid = p.projectid
                        WHERE p.datefrom > '$datefrom' AND p.datefrom < '$dateto'
                        OR p.dateto > '$datefrom' AND p.dateto < '$dateto'
                        OR '$datefrom' > p.datefrom AND '$datefrom' < p.dateto
                        OR '$dateto' > p.datefrom AND '$dateto' < p.dateto
                        )
ORDER BY itemid
```

Unfortunately, it isn't.

---

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE i.itemid NOT IN  (
                        SELECT r.itemid 
                        FROM reservelist r inner join project p on r.projectid = p.projectid
                        WHERE p.datefrom BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'
                        OR p.dateto BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'
                        OR '$datefrom' BETWEEN p.datefrom AND p.dateto
                        OR '$dateto' BETWEEN p.datefrom AND p.dateto
                        )
```

Works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to group your conditions. Instead of:

```
OR p.dateto > '$datefrom' AND p.dateto < '$dateto'
```

You want to write:

```
OR (p.dateto > '$datefrom' AND p.dateto < '$dateto')
```

This way, you have the same functionality as BETWEEN (only with a strict "greater than" condition). Same goes for your other conditions.

In the end, your WHERE clause should look like this:

```
WHERE (p.datefrom > '$datefrom' AND p.datefrom < '$dateto')
OR (p.dateto > '$datefrom' AND p.dateto < '$dateto')
OR ('$datefrom' > p.datefrom AND '$datefrom' < p.dateto)
OR ('$dateto' > p.datefrom AND '$dateto' < p.dateto)
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response, but it still doesn't want to work. With or without quotes the already reserved item appears in the list and I can reserve it over and over again. With the BETWEEN query, it is working..